# Sending React Native logs to remote server (Android)

Tags: android, react-native

I am building an app using React Native in which I need to be able to redirect logs from a smartphone device to a remote server, I have been successful in doing this on iOS(Swift) with the following code:

```
RCTAddLogFunction { (level, source, fileName, lineNumber, message) in
    if let msg = message {
        self.write(message: msg) // Writes to websocket
    }
}
```

So what I'm wondering now is if there's an equivalent to `RCTAddLogFunction` for Android or what the most appropriate solution would be.

Thanks!